# Kubuntu partial freezing during high load

Tags: kubuntu, freeze, 23.10

Often when my system is on high load (playing games and compiling stuff at the same time for example), my Kubuntu system would partially freeze for a few dozen minutes. It starts with immense lag, followed by a near complete freeze of the system. In this state you can only move the cursor very slowly and pretty much nothing else. The only option is to spam ALT+F4 until the system unfreezes.

System Specs:

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 23.10
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.8
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.110.0
Qt Version: 5.15.10
Kernel Version: 6.5.0-10-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 16 × 13th Gen Intel® Core™ i5-13400
Memory: 15.4 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060/PCIe/SSE2
Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
Product Name: B760M DS3H AX DDR4
```

Does anybody know the cause of this?

Comment: You may want to check whether the system runs out of memory while the various tasks run. This can be done by e.g. using `top` in a terminal window.
When the systems runs out of RAM it will start to use the swap space which results in a less responsive system.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your system using too much memmory when running this tasks, you can always watch your memmory usage from terminal by using

```
watch free -m
```

When executing tasks that demand significant memory resources, it is crucial to observe the memory utilization closely. If the system's RAM usage approaches its capacity, it could indeed lead to system instability or freezing.

Comment: I don't have any swap space on my system, do you think adding some would help?